# How do I properly construct an UPDATE statement that references an attached database table?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

this question pertains to Python3's sqlite3 module (DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases).

I am trying to update a sqlite3 database column where there are equivalent values in an attached database table. I fail to understand why my sqlite statement fails with the error message "no such column". I posted a minimal example below. My goal is to update the "number" column in table_b for rows where the "word" column matches the "string" column of table_a from the attached database "db1".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA for your time.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('db1.dat')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE table_a (string TEXT)''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO table_a VALUES ('Lorem')''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO table_a VALUES ('ipsum')''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO table_a VALUES ('dolor')''')
conn.commit()
c.close

conn = sqlite3.connect('db2.dat')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE table_b (word TEXT, number INTEGER)''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('sit', 0)''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('amet', 0)''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('dolor', 0)''')
conn.commit()
c.execute('''ATTACH 'db1.dat' AS db1''')
c.execute('''UPDATE table_b SET number = 1 WHERE table_b.word = table_a.string''')
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/newb/sandbox/<ipython-input-1-3659f61710d7> in <module>()
     17 c.execute('''PRAGMA database_list''')
     18 c.fetchall()
---> 19 c.execute('''UPDATE table_b SET number = 1 WHERE table_b.word = table_a.string''')

OperationalError: no such column: table_a.string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.
The update statement that I was looking for is:

```
c.execute('''UPDATE table_b SET number = 1 WHERE table_b.word IN (SELECT string FROM table_a)''')
```

I found guidance here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm